# How to use fb's social plugin for registering users in django

Tags: python, django, facebook

I'm trying to integrate the registration social plugin on my django application, but I'm having some problems reading the signed request that fb sends back.

Are there some examples that show how to decode the request in Python?

Answer (score 0):

This is some sample code from Facebook on writing a Canvas application. You are writing a website using their API, but the signed request stuff is similar. Here are the relevant parts:

https://github.com/facebook/runwithfriends/blob/master/main.py#L276
https://github.com/facebook/runwithfriends/blob/master/main.py#L160

and here is their separate SDK:

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

There are already libraries for using Facebook login on your website, try here:

https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration